# Use of 'an hire' in legal writing

Tags: indefinite-articles, legalese

I received legal documents pertaining to hiring in which every use of the word 'hire' was proceded by the indefinite article 'an'. Example:

> An hire takes place once...

Is this correct or acceptabel usage of 'an'. If so can you explain when it is correct and why?

Comment: In what country/city was the document produced and can you give the entire sentence (without any personal info.)?

Comment: Are you asking: 1) whether the article should be "a" or "an"; OR 2) whether it should be there at all?

Answer (score 2):

That would only be correct in a dialect that pronounced hire like 'ire, dropping the initial h sound. In general use an if and only if the next word starts with a vowel sound (an hour, an essay, an MOT test).

Comment: No, this is not *necessarily* true—although it's likely. I grew up (in Canada), hearing *an his-torical*, with the *h* pronounced rather than being silent. Even though that goes against common usage, there are some exceptions. For some people, that *might* be idiomatic.

Comment: @JasonBassford: The first syllable of "historical" is unstressed, which is important for one version of the a/an rule. But "hire", being a monosyllable, is stressed on the first syllable.